# How to wait for a group of events to finish before starting a new one with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of events to load some html in some divs:

```
$("#id1").load("1.html");
$("#id2").load("2.html");
$("#id3").load("3.html");
$("#id4").load("4.html");
```

and then I hide a loading bar:

```
$("#load-bar").hide();
```

but of course everything happens at the same time.

How can I group the load elements together and only execute the hide function after they are all done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery .when and multiple .load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856924/jquery-when-and-multiple-load)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$.when($("#id1").load("1.html"), $("#id2").load("2.html"), $("#id3").load("3.html"), $("#id4").load("4.html")).done(function () {
    $("#load-bar").hide();
});
```

---

**Updated after [Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598511/johan) comment**

```
var load1 = $.ajax({
    url: '1.html',
    dataType: 'html'
}),
    load2 = $.ajax({
        url: '2.html',
        dataType: 'html'
    }),
    load3 = $.ajax({
        url: '3.html',
        dataType: 'html'
    }),
    load4 = $.ajax({
        url: '4.html',
        dataType: 'html'
    });

$.when(load1, load2, load3, load4).done(function () {
    $("#load-bar").hide();
});
```

---

If you have a variable amount of requests to make you can use --> Commented By  [Bill Criswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191226/bill-criswell)

```
$.when.apply($, arrayOfDeferreds).done(doWhenAllDone);
```

Comment: If you have a variable amount of requests to make you can use `$.when.apply($, arrayOfDeferreds).done(doWhenAllDone);`

Comment: @BillCriswell Ty added that to answer :)

Comment: it works indeed but my only question is how do I attach the htmls to the divs as in the original code?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way but I'm doing it with the ajax success adding a function that uses append

Comment: well it should not be the right way, I'm getting errors. I still need to bind the htmls to the divs.

Comment: @Bastian Try doing like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856924/jquery-when-and-multiple-load